# Android multiline number edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline, android-input-method

I want to create an EditText in Android which has several lines and number input. It is for the input of a matrix. I already have a solution to set `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` and then `setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY)`. However, this does not work when editing the edittext in horizontal orientation and it also does not show the slash (`/`) which I need to input fractions. If I set the input type to`setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)`, it also does not work in horizontal orientation and always after I enter a space, it switches to the normal input keyboard. Do you know any solution which would help me?

Answer (score 6):

In this way could be created multiline EditText which allow only numbers and  has digit keyboard

```
   <EditText

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,/"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|phone" />
```

Comment: You do not need comma between numbers.

Comment: Wrong answer. `textMultiLine` should be combined with TYPE_CLASS_TEXT

Answer (score 4):

try it , i use this for edittext with multiline and inputtye phone

```
   <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_mobiles"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\n"
            android:inputType="phone"/>
```

replace number instead of phone

Comment: this does not allow to enter commas in input e.g: 12154,454

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <EditText 
      android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
      android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,/" 
      android:hint="Only letters, / allowed"/>
```

Comment: Have to add \n to allow new lines, too. However, the number keyboard still disappears when I press the space key...

Answer (score 0):

Try it, i use this for `Edittext` with multiline number

```
android:singleLine="false"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be:

```
   <EditText
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|number"
        android:singleLine="false" 
        android:digits= "0123456789" />
```

Not:

```
   <EditText
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|number"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:digits= "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" />
```

If you put comma into digits, then you can take , as input.
Like: **12154,454** .
Thanks