# Android: EditText - multiple lines and android:inputType

Tags: android, android-edittext, newline

I am having a (?simple?) problem with EditText. Whenever I type in it, the text stays in the same line even when I get to the edge of the screen instead of creating a new line.  I sure I remember it doing this by default before, but I can't seem to get it to work know...

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
```

EDIT: The problem is because a have android:inputType. Is there any way to have the input type with the multiple lines?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can set more than one property on the input type by separating the flags with the pipe "|" character. Try a setting like:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

Complete Code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:lines="3"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly :-)

Comment: For inputType="number"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153237/android-multiline-number-edittext